# How to password protect a crontab in unix

Tags: unix, cron

We need to password protect the activities on the crontab, for ex even if we try

```
crontab -l
```

or

```
crontab -e
```

or

```
crontab -r
```

We would have to enter a password to go to the next level(viewing/editing/deleting) even if we are root user.

Kindly suggest some mechanisms.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. And it's off-topic for SO, it will probably be migrated to serverfault.com.

Comment: You can have a look at `/etc/cron.d/allow` and `/etc/cron.d/deny`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't trust the root user on your system I would say you have big problems. I don't think there is any way to securely protect anything from root - by definition this user can do what they like, including removing any protection you put in place to try to enfore a password  when executing crontab.

Comment: This is very true and to the point.

Comment: the question arises because crontab -r removes everything without even asking for confirmation :(

Comment: Yep, 'e' and 'r' are dangerously close on qwerty... you could use a shell alias/script.

Comment: @loreb, thanks for the information ,Any pointers for creating the script?

Comment: @vivek-iyer, just pick whichever language you're comfortable with (shell,perl,python,...), parse all the options (eg using the shell you'd resort to getopts, with a trailing 's') and check for the dangerous option: if it's there, ask for a confirmation, otherwise just pass the arguments to the original crontab

Comment: here's a skeleton using the shell (sorry for the borked newlines, how do they work in a comment?): #! /bin/sh
while getopts 'u:lre' flag ; do
    case $flag in
        ([ule])
            # ok, crontab will do it
            ;;
        (r)
            # need confirmation!
            ;;
        (*)
            # write usage message, exit nonzero
            ;;
    esac
done
exec original_crontab "$@"